# Does my prediction model predict the right thing?

Tags: python, dataframe, prediction, xgboost

**Situation:** students take tests that have different characteristics (length of text, number of difficult words, they may or may not contain pictures etc.). The tests can be either "Hard" or "Easy". To predict whether they ae hard or easy, I used all these features and created several accurate models (with `XGBoost` for example).

**Now:** students can either fail (0) or pass (1) a test and I want to predict whether they would fail or pass. This is similar to a recommendation system, where users like or dislike items. That's why I could apply a collaborative-filtering system that works well but obviously we need lots of data for that.

**Problem**: I want to use the characteristics of the tests to predict whether they would fail or pass. But if I have a dataframe like this:

```
studentId          testId        Length        Words      picture      result
       s1              t1            10         8.50           0            0
       s1              t2            11         9.80           1            0
       s1              t3            11        10.40           1            1
       s2              t2            11         9.80           1            0
       s2              t4            60         9.99           0            1
       s3              t7            40         6.45           0            1
```

And I just do (obviously with the necessary imports):

```
cols_to_drop = ['testId', 'studentId']
df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
X = df.drop('result', axis=1) 
y = df['result']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)
model = XGBClassifier() 
model.fit(X_train, y_train) 
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

Does it really answer the question? ("Would student `s3` fail or pass the test `t7`?"). I feel like this is really just what I did for predicting whether a test is hard or easy, but this time it's "hard" or "easy" from the student's perspective.

I looked into content-based filtering and it seems so different from what I am doing here and that's why I'm worried.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing feature about the dataset, you need at least the grade of student. Students with higher grade generally will pass and students with lower grade generally would fail given the same test number.

Your model depends on your training datasets. You can then measure the accuracy of the model by using your test datasets. If the model gets an accuracy of 100% on the test then the model is doing the right thing.

Comment: I don't have this feature because there are no grades. It's just a set of "multiple choice questions" (these are the "tests") that students answer, right or wrong, and maybe then repeat them. My concern was whether the block of code that I wrote, that uses the dataframe that I wrote above, predicts the right thing (how accurate it does that doesn't matter right now).

Comment: To check if your code is correct , generate an obvious datasets (add student grades, higher grade will not fail on easy test, lower grade will fail on hard test), train a model and let it predict and check its accuracy. if accuracy is low then there must something wrong with your code.